# I am trying to modify a method that returns an error string so that it can accept a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, constants, subroutine, bless

Here is the current method:

```
sub new {
    my ($package, $message) = (shift, shift);
    my %params = @_;
    return bless { message => $message, %params }, $package;
}
```

This method returns basically an error string , but I want to modify it so it will also be able to take my new error structure and return the string from the error hash. I can't get my head around how to use bless.
The %params accepts runtime parameter but they can be ignored for now I would think.

Here is the error structure:

```
 # this constant is an example of an error library (just included 1 error for example)
    use constant {

        CABLING_ERROR => {
        errorCode => 561,
        message => "Cabling incorrect to device in server A4r, contact DCT ",
        tt => { template => 'cable'},
        fatal => 1,
        link =>'http://www.error-fix.com/cabling
        },
};
```

I just started throwing down some code to start , it's a poor attempt but this is how I began modifying the new() method:

```
sub new {
    my ($package, $message) = (shift, shift);
    # defining new error hash
    my $hash($errorCode, $message, $tt, $fatal, $link) = (shift, shift, shift, shift);
    my %params = @_;

    if(exists $hash->{errorCode}) {
    return bless { errorCode => $errorCode, message => $message, tt => $tt, fatal => $fatal, link => $link}, %params;
}   
    else {
        return bless { message => $message, %params }, $package;
}
}
```

My understanding of bless is that it makes object of hash refs.
The errors are held in the constant list. 
Here is an example of how it is to be executed:

```
if(!device_model) {
    die  ARC::Builder::Error->new(CABLING_ERROR);

}
```

UPDATE:
I have been trying to unit test your solution @simbabque but I keep getting an empty string as a return value instead of the error message string.
Maybe it's my test that it isn't set up correctly? Below is an example of the test I created:

```
my $error = CABLING_ERROR;

my $exp_out_A = ($error->{message});

my $error_in = new($error);

diag($error_in);

is($error_in, $exp_out_A, 'Correct message output');
```

Comment: Why do you have a constant? Please [edit] your question and add an example call for the constructor with input and output. - Actually, do you know at all what the `bless` does? It doesn't sound like that. Please try to also explain a bit more what this is supposed to do, and in what context. I smell an X/Y problem. ;)

Comment: @simbabque makes good points. I am just going to point out that *if* you need to define a constant hash, you should use a module such as `Const::Fast`. The fields of `CABLING_ERROR` defined above are modifiable. Also, post code that others can easily run. Your code should ***NOT*** contain any *syntax errors* unless those are the focus of your question.

Comment: You are better off using [Exception::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::Class) or [Throwable::Error](https://metacpan.org/pod/Throwable::Error)

Comment: I will take a look at Const::Fast . Apologies , I am very new to perl.  The system already has its own Exception module in place. I am only dealing with the fatal errors that will cause the system to crash (die).

Comment: Besides the syntax error in the last code block (it's supposed to be `Arc::Builder::Error` with two `::`), I think it might be wiser to subclass that thing, and make one subclass per error type. That way you have something that is _constant_ (adjective), but you are avoiding complicated constants. I agree with Sinan about the exception modules though. What `bless` does can best be described as taking a data structure and sticking a label on it. But it does not have to be a hash. The hash is just very typical, because it's flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want is your constructor to distinguish between if it was called with a message string, or with a hash of a known form that contains the message string. Basically you want to *coerce* the message attribute.

```
sub new {
  my ($package, $thing) = (shift, shift);
  my %params = @_;

  if (ref $thing eq 'HASH') {
    return bless { message => $thing->{message}, %params }, $package;
  }

  return bless { message => $thing, %params }, $package;
}
```

That's it. Just check the `ref` of the param you are getting. If it's a hash reference, it will be `'HASH'`. If it's a simple string, it will be `undef`.

In case you want to build up more `%params` automatically from your hash reference, that would look something like this.

```
return bless { message => $thing->{message}, foo => $thing->{foo}, %params }, $package;
```